# Prevent parameter propagation

Tags: bash

When I call a script inside another one, the parameters I give to the first one are automatically propagate to the second one.

a.sh :

```
echo "a running"
source b.sh blablabla
source b.sh
```

b.sh :

```
echo "b running"
echo $1
```

Which gives :

```
$source a.sh hello
a running
b running
blablabla
b running
hello
```

EDIT :

```
set ""
echo "a running"
source b.sh blablabla
source b.sh
```

Can be a solution since set "" set the first parameter to an empty string

Comment: `set ""` doesn't reset the parameters. It sets the first positional parameters to the empty string. You probably mean `set --`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `source`, everything inside b.sh is being read and executed as if it were part of a.sh - so it has access to the positional parameters passed to a.sh. What are you trying to accomplish here - is it actually necessary to use `source`? You can avoid this behaviour by running the script instead of sourcing it:

```
./b.sh
```

Or:

```
bash b.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have tried, but now I have the explanation

Comment: This answer is correct. I just want to add another note here: `source` should not be used when not required. since `b.sh` runs in current shell's context, any changes done by `b.sh` are reflected in `a.sh` or any exit in b.sh will exit entire bash process in which a.sh is running. (I intentionally avoided using terms - parent/child process, because both are running in same process's context.)